# insertar datos en mysql con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

es mi primera vez en este tipo de foros, así que al grano, lo que necesito o bueno he intentado de hacer es restar los campos de caja con total, posterior a eso el resultado se aloje en pesoT, luego pesoT se multiplique con con precio y ese resultado se aloje en totalBS, ahora una vez entendida esa lógica como haría para esa consulta poder mostrarla en PHP, o bueno los resultados de las restas y la multiplicacion se almacene directamente en la base de datos.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: gracias, pense que subi las imagenes del codigo, no lo note

Comment: Porfa, como texto y no como imagen. Nos la pones difícil para replicar tu problema, de la misma forma que no te vamos a poner a transcribir la solución de una imagen